# Global Contact List in Office 365 across all devices

Tags: office-365, contacts, outlook

I'm trying to setup a global contact list on Office 365 Exchange online, which will be visible in all devices.
I've tried the following:

Global Address List - Setting up users in Admin portal. Its not visible in the Contact Lists in Outlook. IT has to be searched by "Address book". Its also not visible on Andriod outlook.

Public Folder - Works in Outlook desktop. but not visible in Andriod/IOS outlook.

SharePoint Contact List - Works for outlook desktop, doesnt propagate. Not viewable on mobile.

Is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about IOS Outlook, but Android Outlook has horrible contacts support. With that being said, here are some solutions you should try:

1. Leverage Microsoft Teams. It should fulfill what you need. Add everyone to Teams, and get the Teams desktop and mobile apps. On mobile, the contacts will be savable to the device.
2. Use Google Contacts. That also has a mobile app and web portal that you can use to add all contacts. Once that's done you can also save contacts to the mobile device.

Once you use one of those methods or something else similar, you should be able to import contacts into Outlook mobile. If that doesn't work for you then you still have the global list of contacts on the mobile device, which Outlook can use when sending emails, etc.